# Is it possible to ZeroFormat a List?

Tags: c#, serialization, zeroformatter

I want to serialize a list of a class type:

```
private static List<TradeData> Trades = new List<TradeData>();

[ZeroFormattable]
private class TradeData
{
    [Index(0)]
    public virtual string Symbol { get; set; }
    [Index(1)]
    public virtual DateTime utcDT { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public virtual int SignedAmount { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public virtual double MidPrice { get; set; }

    public TradeData()
    {
    }
}
```

But I get the error below when I try to do this operation:

```
var zf = ZeroFormatterSerializer.Serialize(Trades);
```

> Message=Type is not supported, occurs invalid error: List`1
>   InnerException:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Type is not supported, occurs
>   invalid error: TradeData
>   InnerException:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied: 'Cobra.Simulz+TradeData'. 
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule
>   module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo()    at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
>   at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.DynamicFormatter.BuildFormatter(ModuleBuilder
>   builder, Type resolverType, Type elementType, Tuple`2[] memberInfos)
>   at ZeroFormatter.Formatters.DynamicFormatter.CreateTTypeResolver,T
>   at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.Formatter.GetBuiltinFormatter[TTypeResolver,T](Type
>   t, TTypeResolver resolver)    at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.Formatter`2..cctor()    at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.ErrorFormatter`2.GetLength()    at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.CollectionFormatter`3..ctor()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)    at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.Formatter.GetBuiltinFormatter[TTypeResolver,T](Type
>   t, TTypeResolver resolver)    at
>   ZeroFormatter.Formatters.Formatter`2..cctor()   Source=ZeroFormatter

Comment: Given the exception, it looks like the problem is that it's a private class rather than that it's a list.

Comment: Doh!  That was it - not a list issue at all!